# Validating Hector connection for Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, hector

Supposing I've connected to a cluster with

```
HFactory.getOrCreateCluster(cluster, address)
```

Is there a way to check later on whether or not I'm still connected? There doesn't seem to be an obvious way of doing that from looking through their javadocs.

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to just fire a simple query to the cluster within a try-catch statement and see whether it returns properly, or it throws an exception.